# Material ui Table, edit cell select combobox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material Table https://github.com/mbrn/material-table, my question is

> how I can add a select box when I edit a cell? My header is:

```
{ title: 'Interval', field: 'interval', cellStyle: { fontSize: '13px', color: "#1f4160"}, type: 'select['day]['hour'},
```

My select is gonna be static: hour, day, week

It is possible to do it?
Thanks

Comment: The documentation of that library contains [an example](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable) of how to do that.

Comment: Thanks trixn, the problem is solved.